# Excel VBA - Count colors that are numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I did conditional formatting in cells that contain numbers. Those numbers are the ones that have different colors. I need to count the number of cells that have red numbers, green numbers and blue numbers. Which VBA code should I use?

I have never worked with VBA before.

Thank you.

Comment: No need fo VBA, you can use `COUNTIF/COUNTIFS` with the same conditions as in your conditional formatting. Try it and if you have problems, come back and let us know where the problem is exactly.

Comment: Did you apply Font or Back ground color ?

Comment: Iapplied Interior and Font